# Display subset of array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I want to `puts` the alphabet. So I can do something like:

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z')
alphabet.map do |a|
    puts a
end
```

What I want to do now is exclude the `vowels`.

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z')
vowels   = ['a','e','i','o','u']
alphabet.map do |a|
    puts a unless a == vowels
end
```

I am trying to avoid this:

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z')
alphabet.map do |a|
    puts a unless a == 'a'
    puts a unless a == 'e'
    puts a unless a == 'i'
    puts a unless a == 'o'
    puts a unless a == 'u'
end
```

**How do I syntactically implement the second example so that it works properly?**

Comment: This isn't refactoring, this is changing functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Range can be expanded into an Array. Then you can subtract another array.

```
chars = ('a'..'z').to_a - %w( a e i o u )
chars.each do |a|
    puts a
end
```

As a side note, don't use `#map` unless you really need to. Use `#each` if you don't care about the returning value.

Comment: +1, this is better if you don't need to do anything else with the rest of the alphabet.

Comment: Definitely +1. This reduces the repeated calls to Array#include?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want equality, you want inclusion:

```
puts a if vowels.include? a
```

Also, you're using `map` (same as `collect`) which will actually return the results of the `puts` statements. Unless you actually *need* that, use `each`. Or find the letters that match the condition and use that collection to print the results later.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Array#include?` method:

```
puts a unless vowels.include? a
```

Source: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Array#include%3F-instance_method

Answer (score 2):

You can even get rid of the loop. This preserves the original alphabet.

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z')
puts (alphabet.to_a - %w(a e i o u)).join('\r')
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) would work, too:

```
('a'..'z').grep(/[^aeiou]/) { |a| puts a }
```

Or simply

```
puts ('a'..'z').grep(/[^aeiou]/)
```

Comment: I would go with this one..Awesome.. +1